# Does google provide ddos protection for compute engine vms?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

Does google compute engine offer ddos protection for any virtual machines created within a project,  I have read that it does can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different [types of DDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) and Google would guard VM from some of them (*SYN flood, ICMP flood, etc.*) simply because it's on shared network infrastructure but as far as I know/understand it would not be able to protected from fake HTTP requests.